# Laravel 5: php artisan migrate issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-migrations

I have correctly specified the configuration in database.php file.

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'laravel5'),
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'abc123'),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ],
```

when i run this on console

```
php artisan migrate
```

It gives the error
**Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES)'**

Why is it is giving this error and what is the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In laravel first priority is .env file so that if there is already set a configuration in .env file that will work first,if not found any configuration in .env file then your database.php file will work.In .env file

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=database
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

If you want to use database.php for configuration then you don't need to use `env()` function. After removing the `env()` function the updated code will be

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => 'localhost',
    'database'  => 'laravel5',
    'username'  => 'root',
    'password'  => 'abc123',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
    'strict'    => false,
],
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the `.env` file, You need to specify the database information on `.env` file

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=laravel5
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=abc123
```

Comment: It solved the problem. Isn't it redundant to specify the same configuration on two different places?

Comment: @alishaukat Only need to specify in env file

Comment: then why do we have this configuration in database.php?

Comment: @alishaukat Check this https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/saving-database-details-in-databasephp-instead-of-env-in-laravel-5

Comment: I use the .env file, but I *think* I read somewhere that migrate functions use an entry in database.php of

'mysql_testing' => [ <config here> ] whereas the 'mysql' one is used for the app